# group documents by array of ObjectIds

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.test.insert([
  { name: 'one', refs: [ObjectId('111'), ObjectId('222'), ObjectId('333')] },
  { name: 'two', refs: [ObjectId('222'), ObjectId('333')] },
  { name: 'three', refs: [ObjectId('222'), ObjectId('333'), ObjectId('111')] },
])
```

Ideally, I wan't to group documents if they have all the same references (and the same number of references), doesn't matter which order they are kept inside the array field. Like this

```
[
  {
    names: ['one', 'three'],
  },
  {
    names: ['two'],
  }
]
```

As far as I understand I need to:

1. Sort `refs` elements
2. Convert `ObjectId`s to string
3. Concat all id strings to a single string and save to a specific field
4. Group by that field

Please note, that real documents are huge enough (say, contain some heavy 'data' field, `refs` itself can contain 0-10 items in average, 50 at most) and filtered input can contain thousands of documents.

Would this be the most efficient way in terms of productivity (CPU + RAM)?

**UPDATE**

Sorry for not mentioning about an important detail: there are other non-array fields which should take part in grouping. For instance

```
{
  name: 'can',
  color: 'green',
  refs: [ObjectId(1), ObjectId(2)],
  material: 'plastic',
  price: 50,
}
```

say I need to group them by `color` + `refs` + `material`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single `$group` with `$setUnion`:

```
db.test.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: { $setUnion: "$refs" }, names: { $push: "$name" } } },
   { $unset: "_id" }
])
```

If you have more fields to group, simply add them to `_id`:

```
{ $group: { 
   _id: { 
      refs: { $setUnion: "$refs" }, 
      color: "$color", 
      material: "$material" 
   }, 
   names: { $push: "$name" } 
} },
```

Comment: Hi @Wernfried Domscheit, sorry, my example was missing an important detail. Can you please look at it?